# async.parallel not working like asynchronous in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a below code.

var async = require('async');

```
async.parallel({

        f2: function(callback){
            for (var i=0;i< 100000000;i++){

            }
            console.log("f2");
            callback(null,"function 2");
        },
        f1: function(callback){

            console.log("f1");
            callback(null,"function 1");
        },

    },
    function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

and I run above...

result:

```
f2
f1
{ f2: 'function 2', f1: 'function 1' }
```

Why first result f2 ? 
Why not f1?
f1 function is simple more than f2 function.

I think.. I cant make like asynchronous.

I don't want use SetTimeOut , proccess.NextTick etc...

Comment: `async` is for managing asynchronous code. Your code isn't asynchronous.

Comment: please indent your code properly

Answer (score 1):

The function parallel() is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about parallel execution of code. If your tasks do not use any timers or perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series. Any synchronous setup sections for each task will happen one after the other. JavaScript remains single-threaded. Reference: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel

Comment: I dont think so..   they dont start same time.

Comment: I can not see the console log of the f1 function before the f2 function is finished